# Error when creating a model using Core API

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I tried to follow the tutorial on TensorFlow [official site](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/models_and_layers#creating_models_with_the_core_api) to create a machine learning model based on Core API. But I got the following error:

> Error: Argument 'b' passed to 'matMul' must be a Tensor or TensorLike, but got 'null'

I am working on windows 10 and with tfjs@1.5.2

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const tfcore = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-core')


const w1 = tf.variable(tf.randomNormal([784, 32]));
const b1 = tf.variable(tf.randomNormal([32]));
const w2 = tf.variable(tf.randomNormal([32, 10]));
const b2 = tf.variable(tf.randomNormal([10]));

function model(x) {
  console.log(w1);
  return x.matMul(w1).add(b1).relu().matMul(w2).add(b2).softmax();
}


model(tfcore);
```

Could you please help me with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [@edkeveked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60542699) stated you need to supply two tensors for [`tf.matMul`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#matMul):

**approach 1**

```
const a = tf.tensor2d([1, 2], [1, 2]);
const b = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2]);

a.matMul(b);
```

or **approach 2**

```
const a = tf.tensor2d([1, 2], [1, 2]);
const b = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2]);

tf.matMul(a, b);
```

in your example, by passing in `tfcore` to `model()` you are using **approach 2** and therefore need to pass a second tensor to `matMul`. however, if you pass a tensor to `model()` it should work like **approach 1**.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My main problem is that I want to rebuild a model from existing weights in Float32Array format. Is there any solution to rebuild it using Layers API or Core API ?

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all, you are multiplying a tensor by null (the second parameter defaults to null).

```
tf.matMul(tensor)
```

You need to supply a second tensor for the matrix multiplication